# Issue while trying to initialize the react property

Tags: reactjs, dotenv, react-18

**Issue details**

> 1. .env value not initialized in the react property
> 2. siteKey value is always blank

**Property in react**

```
const [siteKey] = useState(process.env.REACT_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY);
```

**Key in .env**

```
REACT_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY='some key'
```

**Html**

```
<ReCAPTCHA sitekey={siteKey}/>
```

Comment: You don't need to use a hook here because you don't use a setter. Can you try with a basic `const siteKey = process.env.REACT_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY` ?

Comment: are you using create-react-app? if so, the env variables should be prefixed by `REACT_APP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw Some Issue in your code, First thing is,`UseState` hook initialization is wrong.
It Should be,

```
  const [siteKey, setsiteKey] = useState(process.env.REACT_APP_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY);
```

And also You don't need to use this environment variable as `useState`, because it is not changing so, when you need to access environment variable, use as below,

ex:`const siteKey=process.env.REACT_APP_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY;`

**Other Important Issues are,**

Your environment variable should prefix with the `REACT_APP_` in the .env file.
ex:`process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_VARIABLE`

And possible Issue can be, your .env file is not in your root which is that, within the same directory as the package. json file.

Comment: I don't find any issue with `useState`, we are allowed to use `useState` without setter method.

Comment: @HarshPatel please read the answer before the commenting. There are no point to have a useState for having environment variable  values. since it is not changing, it is constant for the project.

Answer (score 3):

Main issue is with your environment declaration, as per [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/):

> You must create custom environment variables beginning with
> REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to
> avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could
> have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require
> you to restart the development server if it is running.

As you don't have any setter method needed for `useState`, you can define your variable just with `const`, like:

```
const siteKey = process.env.REACT_APP_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

**Key in .env should be** like as shown below

REACT_APP_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=some_key_value

Also whenever you edit your **.env** file you need to restart your React app to take effect of your modified file.